# Using differentials to optimize a function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, calculus, optimization

I've read in a [paper](http://math.oregonstate.edu/bridge/papers/differentials.pdf) by Tevian Dray an alternative way to solve optimization problems manipulating "differentials". Here is an example of how it works (next I quote the paper).

> Consider the problem of minimizing the length of a piecewise straight path connecting two fixed points with a given line, as shown in Figure 1. For instance, the line could represent a river along which a single pumping station is to be built to serve two towns. The distances $C$, $D$, and $S = a + b$ are specified; the goal is to determine $a$ and/or $b$ so that $ℓ = p + q$ is minimized.
>
> The standard solution to this problem involves expressing $a, b, p, q$, and hence $ℓ$, in terms of a single variable, typically $a$, then minimizing $ℓ$ by computing $\frac {dℓ} {da}$ and setting it equal to zero. This computation is straightforward, but involves the derivatives of square roots and some messy algebra.
>
> [image: Figure 1: Minimizing the combined distance p + q between two fixed points and a line]
>
> Consider instead the following solution, using differentials. First, write down what you
>   know:
>   $$a + b = S$$
>   $$a^2 + C^2 = p^2$$
>   $$b^2 + D^2 = q^2$$
>   $$p + q = ℓ$$
>
> where $S, C, D$ are known constants. Next, take the differential of each equation:
>   $$da + db = 0$$
>   $$2a\ da = 2p\ dp$$
>   $$2b\ db = 2q\ dq$$
>   $$dp + dq = dℓ$$
>
> We are trying to minimize $ℓ$, so we set $dℓ = 0$ to obtain
>
> $$0 = dℓ = dp + dq = \frac{a}{p} da + \frac{b}{q} db = \left ( \frac{a}{p} - \frac{b}{q} \right ) da $$
>
> so that
>
> $$\frac{b^2}{a^2}=\frac{q^2}{p^2}=\frac{b^2+D^2}{a^2+C^2}$$
>
> which (since lengths must be positive) quickly yields
>
> $$\frac{b}{a}=\frac{D}{C}$$
>
> so that
>
> $$a =\frac{CS}{C + D}$$ $$b =\frac{DS}{C + D}$$
>   and it is straightforward to verify that these values do in fact minimize $ℓ$.

I've tried to use this method to solve some problems, and sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't (when I have to optimize a function $f(x,y,z)$ with two constraint function $g_1(x,y,z)=c_1$ and $g_2(x,y,z)=c_2$, generally I have to use Lagrange multipliers because this manipulation of differentials doesn't lead to the correct answer). Also, I've seen this method been used in some thermodynamics textbooks.

So, **my questions are** why this manipulation of differentials is capable to solve optimization problems? When this leads to a wrong answer? Where (a book, video, etc.) can I learn more about this method? (to use it systematically)

---

Note: I've also asked this question on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175504/using-differentials-to-optimize-a-function)

Comment: As much as I personally like this question I should tell you someone will probably comment here saying that cross-posting between sites is frowned upon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question. (No migrate vote [as it already exists on math](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175504))

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to treat differentials and infinitesimals?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92925/how-to-treat-differentials-and-infinitesimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be able to use it to solve constrained optimization. Let me give you sort of the big-picture overview.

So you know that if $du$ is small compared to $u$ then you can linearize about $u$. When you want to generalize to more variables, you have to do partial derivatives: for example $$ f(x + dx, y + dy, z + dz) \approx f(x,y,z) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{y,z} dx + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{x,z} dy + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right)_{x,y} dz. $$ There is a nice shorthand for this expression using the dot product of the vector $d\vec r = (dx, dy, dz)$ as $$ f(\vec r + d\vec r) \approx f(\vec r) + \nabla f \cdot d\vec r.$$ 
If you calculate it out, the last term here is the "differential" approach that you get above. Your constraints will generate fixed conditions for $d\vec r$,
$$\nabla g_1 \cdot d\vec r = \nabla g_2 \cdot d\vec r = 0.$$

Now we want to find the points $\vec r$ such that, if $d\vec r$ obeys the constraints, then $\nabla f \cdot d\vec r = 0$. There is no reason that I see that this should lead to a wrong answer. In fact, it leads to a matrix solution $$\left[\begin{array}{c}(\nabla f)^T\\(\nabla g_1)^T\\(\nabla g_2)^T\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}dx \\ dy \\ dz\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{array}\right]$$which amounts to looking for a nontrivial kernel of that matrix, which amounts to saying that the vectors are linearly dependent, which says that $\nabla f + \lambda_1 \nabla g_1 + \lambda_1 \nabla g_2 = \nabla (f + \lambda_1 g_1 + \lambda_2 g_2) = 0$, which gives you back exactly the method of Lagrange multipliers! So these are totally equivalent approaches if you do them correctly.

I guess my basic question is, "are you sure that you've been doing partial derivatives correctly when doing constrained optimization?" Because the general idea of trying to do a simultaneous-solution of differential-based equations seems pretty solid to me.

Comment: Irrespective of whether this is a good answer, I believe general policy is that if a question is obviously either off-topic or cross-posted, one shouldn't answer until those issues are resolved. I suggest you consult the FAQs and policies on this matter to know what you should do in future on these matters.