# Math approach to Classical Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, resource-recommendations

I have a basic knowledge about differential geometry, tensor calculus,.. but nothing about Thermodynamics. There are a lot of references of *classical theormodynamics* for physics.

There exists a formal book for mathematician of *classical theormodynamics* ?

Comment: You should go with _Caratheodory Thermodynamics_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [References about rigorous thermodynamics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5614/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Introduction to differential forms in thermodynamics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32296/)

Comment: Differential forms in thermodynamics: https://www.av8n.com/physics/thermo-forms.htm , https://www.av8n.com/physics/thermo-forms.htm (by J. Denker, https://www.av8n.com/physics/ ).